# How to Extract Text from a String in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have text that needs to be extracted from a string into certain cells based on guide text within the string.

I have tried using various methods but these methods do not typically function when guide text is moved or missing which can occur with the input process.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eNXa0tTzYVXVrapc8mt-V83PrkKDZwEXp1EQMYGmsRU/edit?usp=sharing

The result should output the correct data text following the guide text.

Comment: Would you please complete the expected successful outcome for **all** 5 rows of your spreadsheet.

Comment: This question is useless now that you've removed the Google sheets link. Provide data in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR({
 INDEX(SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A&"(", "\(1\)(.+)\("), "("),,1),
 INDEX(SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A&"(", "\(2\)(.+)\("), "("),,1),
 INDEX(SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A&"(", "\(3\)(.+)\("), "("),,1)}))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Hello! Thank you, this worked out perfectly!

Comment: For some reason this will remove any leading zeros if they are within the input area ir: (1)00123

Comment: yeah, use this: `=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(IFERROR({
 INDEX(SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT(SUBSTITUTE(A2:A, 0, "♦")&"(", "\(1\)(.+)\("), "("),,1),
 INDEX(SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT(SUBSTITUTE(A2:A, 0, "♦")&"(", "\(2\)(.+)\("), "("),,1),
 INDEX(SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT(SUBSTITUTE(A2:A, 0, "♦")&"(", "\(3\)(.+)\("), "("),,1)}), "♦", 0))` - https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBCAM.png

Comment: Wow! This is so impressive! You have thoroughly answered my question. If I may followup with another question. Would this work in a use case where the parenthesis number were two digits (12) or (01). I plugged it in and it did not work and am very curious as to why it would not work. Thanks!

Comment: actually I think it does work unless that parenthesis number includes a zero if I am correct. As it is being substituted I believe.

Comment: @AHCB yeah, indeed

Comment: Do you think it would be possible to fix the leading zero and retain functionality of the zero in the parenthesis, or is this bumping into the limitations of the complexity of this functions?

Comment: so instead of (1)00123 you want it to be 01100123 ? eg () = 01 ? and 00123 as value?

Comment: I think if the number were to be (01)00042891 or (10)000318541

Comment: I see... try: `=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(IFERROR({
 INDEX(SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "(0)", "♥"), 0, "♦")&"(", "\(♥1\)(.+)\("), "("),,1),
 INDEX(SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT(SUBSTITUTE(A2:A, 0, "♦")&"(", "\(2\)(.+)\("), "("),,1),
 INDEX(SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT(SUBSTITUTE(A2:A, 0, "♦")&"(", "\(3\)(.+)\("), "("),,1)})), "♥|♦", "0"))` - https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFzfw.png

Comment: Thank you for all your help! You are much appreciated!